# (In a beta decay) Between what particles are W bosons exchanged?

Tags: particle-physics, weak-interaction, bosons

According to what I've learned, when two electrons repel each other, photons are exchanged between the electrons, and gluons are exchanged between quarks in a nucleus. However, in beta decay, it seems like W (plus or minus) bosons are just emitted from quarks and the W bosons quickly decay into a pair of leptons.

Q1. So, in case of beta decays or just weak interactions generally, between what particles are W bosons exchanged?

Q2. Also, in what sense can one tell the weak interaction as a force? Electromagnetic forces and strong nuclear forces exchanged by photons and gluons, respectively, fall under my (limited) sense of force as there are obviously attraction and repulsion going on. However, just emissions of W bosons do not seem to be a force. Is it called a force because the emission of W bosons causes the momenta of particles to change?

Comment: For Q2 see [What exactly does the weak force do?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/562319/what-exactly-does-the-weak-force-do).

Comment: And there are related questions [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/349169/has-the-weak-force-ever-been-measured-as-a-force), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142303/what-is-the-weak-force) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/489168/is-the-weak-force-really-a-force).

Comment: Prof. Sean Carroll recently posted a pretty extensive series about "modern physics" on Youtube.  You might find this one useful (Starting around 28:00) https://youtu.be/Xwpd_z-ipu4?t=1684  I hope this helps.